# Optimize Wordpress image upload, slow and only 1 at a time on Dedicated

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, configuration, server

So I have been at this for weeks with different configurations and I usually am able to figure out by searching but I am not as savvy with server configuration, so I need to ask. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a dedicated server with 5 different WordPress installation, EVERYTHING is blazing fast, in terms of site load speed and posting, etc **EXCEPT** for when I start uploading images using the Wordpress Image upload. ITS SLOW..

When I drag photos over (doesn't matter the size) it takes forever and it seems to be processing one image at a time, unlike when I was on shared hosting, the image upload was a lot faster.. This happens on all my Wordpress installation with different themes and plugins, so I assume this is a server configuration, somewhere.

The process bar would go to 99% for the first image and it sits there for a few minutes, and then goes to the next; also my Admin would stall, so I cannot do anything else on the Admin area until all the images are done uploading. The site doesn't stall and is still functional if I go on a different browser that isn't login as the Admin.

If I go to my process manager, I see that the async-upload.php is running and is only taking up .3% of the CPU and .6% of the memory.

It always finishes but it seems like I am only allowed to have 1 connection or process (sorry, I do not know the correct terms) at a time and then I can request another. Anyone know what server configuration I am missing or have that is causing this? I am on WHM/Cpanel with SSH access, I have tried a few PHP, MySql, and Apache optimizations I found but it hasn't resolved the problem, I am of course doing something wrong with my configuration, anyone can shed some light?

Comment: The same code on different hosting was fast?

Comment: sounds like packet loss to me... lots of retransmitted packets from packet loss would do this. It wouldnt cause site loading issues as most of the assets would be cached in the browser.

Comment: @Mihai, Yes, I moved my sites from a shared hosting to dedicated, when I was on shared, it could not handle all the traffic, therefore I went with a dedicated. So everything was slow BUT at least the image uploading was not as slow as what it is right now on my dedicated server.

Comment: @LuckyBurger, at the moment I am uploading 12 images, under 100kb and it has been 30 mins and is still not done, 3 more to go. Then I went to another computer, cleared the cache and site loads with no problem.

Comment: did you try loading images on that other computer ?

Comment: @LuckyBurger Same problem no matter what computer or where I am at, if you are also wonder I am running a 10/10 business fiber line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the end of its image upload operation, WordPress attempts to resize the incoming images to create thumbnails and medium-sized images. To do this it has to load the images, decompressed, into memory.

That can take a lot of RAM. Try increasing the RAM available to your php instance. Look, in `php.ini` for a stanza like this

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 32M
```

and increase it.

You may also have issues with these settings.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 8M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Also, take a look in your `php_error.log` and `apache_error.log` files and see if you can see any problems. Also, if you're using Google Chrome, open the Javascript console and see if there are any errors showing up.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, I feel like an idiot for not looking at the error logs.. Actually found the root cause.

Comment: @dangcreations ... what was the problem? So this question and answer can serve the next person.

Comment: I had a custom script that connected to SMUSH.IT server to smush all the uploads before posting, The main problem was not being able to connect to Smush.it. I had this in place a few years back and I brought it over without realizing that it was implemented in my core files... Note to self, don't touch the core files.